# How to get imageView bounds on viewModel? (Android MVVM patern with databinding library)

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I'm using the databind library with the MVVM patern just like [archi](https://github.com/ivacf/archi) project on github.

I want to load a image taken from camera in a image view: in other cases I would user this code

```
this.photo = new ObservableField<>(
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), 
R.drawable.img_user_default, null));
```

But now the photo is big and google says I should use this code:

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap ...
```

But inside the viewModel I don't hava any ImageView to get it's dimension! what is the best approach to make it work following the MVVM patern?